# Rails, Spreadsheet gem: How to output spreadsheet data directly to client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spreadsheet

This is probably very simple: I'm creating a workbook (i.e. spreadsheet) using the [Spreadsheet gem](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/), and just want to send the Excel data directly to the client without having to write to a file first.

Right now, I'm writing the workbook to a file in the `tmp` dir, and then sending it using `send_file`, but that seems terribly inelegant as I don't need the file once it's been sent (not even for caching purposes).

Optimally, I'd like to just call `send_data` with the workbook data in a `respond_to :xls` block.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workbook's `write` method takes any path or IO object, so instead of passing it a file or file path you could pass it a StringIO., something along the lines of

```
require 'stringio'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def someaction
    ...
    buffer = StringIO.new
    book.write(buffer)
    buffer.rewind
    send_data buffer.read
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, of course - thanks! I thought it was probably something simple like that